# Why Xcode shows "This app could not be installed at this time." pop-up?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9.2

When I run the project and add the app in simulator for the first time, everything is okay. But when I run it again, Xcode prompts this message as a pop-up window at the end of compilation:

> This app could not be installed at this time.

I already checked [the relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47760643/xcode-this-app-could-not-be-installed-at-this-time), and tried all the advised ways to solve this issue; checking mentioned logs, cleaning project, restarting simulator, changing it, erasing all content and settings in it. Nothing works. I must erase the app and recompile it every time to open the app. Did you get the same message before? Is there any way to detect problem and resolve it? Btw, I use Xcode 9.2 at High Sierra.

Comment: If you're ok, post the project here to check if there's any problem with the project.

Comment: It's commercial. Also I believe it's not about internal settings of the project, some other people work on it without any problem. It's probably something about macOS or Xcode version.

Comment: Did you try a device?

Comment: Nope but my purpose is using currently available simulators without seeing this message.

Comment: Seems to be a problem with info.plist, Have you checked everything there, no invalid values?

Comment: No clues, no witnesses, no nothing.

Comment: I just got this error message too. If I delete the app from the simulator and then everything works fine. Did not change anything in my project except add localisation. And all of a sudden it popped up. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Same here. I didn't change anything but it began to be popped up for some unknown reason. I couldn't find a solution yet. When I figure out it, I'll add an answer.

Comment: The same problem
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47760643/xcode-this-app-could-not-be-installed-at-this-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error pop-up may come up for different reasons. There is no specific reason to see it for now. In my case, a JSON file that I added to Bundle in order to provide mock data triggered this issue. This file was containing a Turkish letter in one of the keys. After I fix it, the pop-up is gone. Interestingly, earlier simulators (<=9.1) work properly if JSON file contains Turkish letter but 9.2 simulators cannot tolerate it.

Comment: This is the case for me too. How can I workaround this keeping letter ı in app display name? Curently I delete app in simulator before each run.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me when I rebuild the project after deleting the derived data folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found a solution. This all started a short time after I let Xcode update my project settings. Specifically on my CocoaPod-Subproject. I removed the pods and reinstalled them and now I am no longer getting the pop-up.

Comment: Sorry for this late response. Probably, the reason of my issue wasn't same with yours. As a workaround, I run the app on earlier simulators. It seems like this one is a version 11.2-specific problem.