# XCode "This app could not be installed at this time."

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, simulator

I'm running into minor annoyance with XCode when building one of my targets, build is successful but once it comes to launching it in simulator I get this prompt

```
This app could not be installed at this time.
```

This happens only when app was installed on the simulator before hand i.e. removing it and building again works fine.

This issue doesn't happen when I run my original target.

Comment: Having the same issue in XCode 9, iOS 11.2

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49361678/1753005

Comment: Force Quit Simulator and Build And Run Xcode it's working !!