# This app could not be installed at this time.Xcode 9.2

Tags: ios, xcode

I have changed my application name and bundle identifier and now when i'm trying to run my app it is showing an error that `This app could not be installed at this time` . Why it is so? Why it isn't running the app?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47760643/xcode-this-app-could-not-be-installed-at-this-time

Comment: Reset the simulator and Clean your project.

Comment: i know its been asked before and i have tried the solutions but it isn't working. @FaysalAhmed

Comment: If you have already tried some things then write that in your question so it will be easier to help you.

Comment: If you google a bit I’m sure you’ll figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the question has been answered but for others encountering the same issue I suggest following:

Check simulator logs, if its printing something useful. First, selecte simulator then from menu option open Debug -> Open System Logs.
Make sure only 1 simulator is running.
Delete the older version of app from the simulator.
If you importing a custom framework, make sure custom framework->bundle-id is not same as currentAppProject->bundle-id. If you are not sure then simply change the bundle-id of current project.
Also some of the simulators can be buggy -> Simply change the simulator, it may resolve the issue, for me changing the simulator worked.