# Why do I keep getting this error when I try to build my project?

Tags: xcode

I started getting the error message after I updated Xcode.
I tried to clean the build folder and restart Xcode.

Screenshot of the error I keep getting:

[image]

Comment: Please provide further explanation. Perhaps XCode and MacOS version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode: "This app could not be installed at this time."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47760643/xcode-this-app-could-not-be-installed-at-this-time)

Comment: Please post text as actual text in your question, not as a picture. Pictures can't be searched or referenced.