# Xcode 11: App could not be installed at this time when trying to run on simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

This is what I see when I click 'Details'. I've tried restarting, cleaning the project, but it doesn't work. The simulator is a black screen.

Please help.

```
This app could not be installed at this time.
Domain: IXUserPresentableErrorDomain
Code: 1
Failure Reason: Could not install at this time.
--
The operation couldn’t be completed. (LSApplicationWorkspaceErrorDomain error -102.)
Domain: LSApplicationWorkspaceErrorDomain
Code: -102
User Info: {
    CFBundleIdentifier = "gumbad.Test";
    Error = RegistrationFailed;
    "_LSFunction" = "-[_LSInstaller _doinstallApplication:atURL:withOptions:installType:notificationJournaller:reply:]";
    "_LSLine" = 627;
}
--
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode: "This app could not be installed at this time."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47760643/xcode-this-app-could-not-be-installed-at-this-time)

Comment: did you fix this?