# Xcode error: This app could not be installed at this time

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode11.1

I'm having issues installing apps on my simulator. I create a new project (making absolutely no modifications) and hit build, it builds successfully and then opens up the simulator.. A this point I get an error that says "This app could not be installed at this time".

I'm running macOS Catalina 10.15 Beta. Installed Xcode 11.1 directly from the Appstore and created a new project which wouldn't deploy with that error. I installed Xcode 11.2 Beta and received the same error as well. I've restarted the computer numerous times, and I've also regularly closed Xcode and the simulator normally as well as force closing them with no luck. I'm not sure what else to try. This is on a 2017 MacBook Pro with Touchbar if it makes any difference.

Here are the error details:

```
This app could not be installed at this time.
Domain: IXUserPresentableErrorDomain
Code: 1
Failure Reason: Could not install at this time.
--
The operation couldn’t be completed. (LSApplicationWorkspaceErrorDomain error -102.)
Domain: LSApplicationWorkspaceErrorDomain
Code: -102
User Info: {
    CFBundleIdentifier = "com.blackhive.SwiftUI-Demo-4";
    Error = RegistrationFailed;
    "_LSFunction" = "-[_LSInstaller _doinstallApplication:atURL:withOptions:installType:notificationJournaller:reply:]";
    "_LSLine" = 627;
}
```

New error details:

```
Process:               com.apple.migrationpluginwrapper [2349]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/XPCServices/com.apple.migrationpluginwrapper.xpc/com.apple.migrationpluginwrapper
Identifier:            com.apple.migrationpluginwrapper
Version:               1.0 (1)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd_sim [2249]
Responsible:           SimulatorTrampoline [2215]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2019-10-30 15:40:44.834 -0700
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.1 (19B77a)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     3.0 (14Y904)
Anonymous UUID:        7F594A3B-E0E3-8F8E-9876-9A1130956853


Time Awake Since Boot: 3100 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        1  Dispatch queue: com.apple.migrationpluginwrapper.plugin.MobileSafari.migrator

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:isDirectory:]: nil string parameter'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called
CoreSimulator 681.14 - Device: iPhone 11 Pro Max (1A97AF8B-70F3-401C-85AF-DB1D7D7A9EC8) - Runtime: iOS 13.1 (17A844) - DeviceType: iPhone 11 Pro Max

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001015d21ee __exceptionPreprocess + 350
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010143fb20 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   Foundation                          0x0000000100f266ec -[NSURL(NSURL) initFileURLWithPath:isDirectory:relativeToURL:] + 0
3   Foundation                          0x0000000100f26c66 +[NSURL(NSURL) fileURLWithPath:isDirectory:] + 54
4   SafariServices                      0x0000000104c806b6 __58+[NSUserDefaults(SafariServicesExtras) _sf_safariDefaults]_block_invoke + 234
5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102206781 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001022079ad _dispatch_once_callout + 20
7   SafariServices                      0x0000000104c805c9 +[NSUserDefaults(SafariServicesExtras) _sf_safariDefaults] + 45
8   MobileSafari                        0x0000000103cc7776 MobileSafari + 30582
9   MobileSafari                        0x0000000103cc1261 MobileSafari + 4705
10  com.apple.migrationpluginwrapper    0x0000000100d64018 __47-[DMMigrationPluginWrapperProxy handleMessage:]_block_invoke_2 + 552
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102205810 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102206781 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010220c4ee _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 707
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010220cf24 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 388
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102216ffc _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 626
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010267c71b _pthread_wqthread + 290
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010267c57b start_wqthread + 15

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000010261c166 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000010261c6cc mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0000000101534af5 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 197
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010152f817 __CFRunLoopRun + 1671
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010152ee66 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 438
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x0000000100ee994f -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 211
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x0000000100ee9b67 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 76
7   libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001025b24e6 _xpc_objc_main + 297
8   libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001025b4b87 xpc_main + 132
9   com.apple.migrationpluginwrapper    0x0000000100d647dd main + 61
10  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000102287d29 start + 1

Thread 1 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.migrationpluginwrapper.plugin.MobileSafari.migrator
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000010262249a __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010267f6cb pthread_kill + 384
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001023aea3c abort + 120
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001020c47f8 abort_message + 231
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001020c49c7 demangling_terminate_handler() + 262
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000010143fd7c _objc_terminate() + 96
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001020d1e97 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001020d1e39 std::terminate() + 41
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000102206795 _dispatch_client_callout + 28
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001022079ad _dispatch_once_callout + 20
10  com.apple.SafariServices        0x0000000104c805c9 +[NSUserDefaults(SafariServicesExtras) _sf_safariDefaults] + 45
11  com.apple.MobileSafari.migrator 0x0000000103cc7776 0x103cc0000 + 30582
12  com.apple.MobileSafari.migrator 0x0000000103cc1261 0x103cc0000 + 4705
13  com.apple.migrationpluginwrapper    0x0000000100d64018 __47-[DMMigrationPluginWrapperProxy handleMessage:]_block_invoke_2 + 552
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000102205810 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000102206781 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000010220c4ee _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 707
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000010220cf24 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 388
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000102216ffc _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 626
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010267c71b _pthread_wqthread + 290
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010267c57b start_wqthread + 15

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010267c56c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 1 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000700009e9d000  rcx: 0x0000700009e9bfd8  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000001703  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x0000700009e9c000  rsp: 0x0000700009e9bfd8
   r8: 0x0000700009e9bea0   r9: 0x0000700009e9c070  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x0000000000001703  r13: 0x0000003000000008  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15: 0x0000000000000016
  rip: 0x000000010262249a  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x000000010267f54b

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148
Trap Number:     133
```

Comment: Are you trying to run it on WatcOS Simulator?

Comment: “I'm running macOS Catalina 10.15 Beta” Update it. Also manually delete all simulators and then make a new one and use it.

Comment: @CodeBender I tried that with no luck

Comment: @kkiermasz No. This is on the iPhone 11 Pro Max simulator

Comment: @matt No update available when I check for an update. I'll try deleting and adding back..

Comment: There must be. Catalina is not in beta at this time. 10.15.1 is final.

Comment: @matt Found it. Had to install it from the Appstore instead of going to updates in settings. Installing it now.. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: I hope it does! In preparation I recommend that you empty the Derived Data folder and manually delete all simulators.

Comment: @matt That seems to have helped! The canvas and simulator seem to be properly working now..
I did get a new error: "com.apple.migrationpluginwrapper quit unexpectedly".
I've attached the problem details above.

Comment: Well, if you can still work on the simulator then just keep reporting the crash to apple and keep going.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode: "This app could not be installed at this time."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47760643/xcode-this-app-could-not-be-installed-at-this-time)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with your OSx, you have 10.15(beta) and it is noted in release notes that XCode and OSX must be "synced". I had the same issue but then I solved it by re-installing MacOS 10.15. I originally had the 10.15 Beta version installed. So make sure you run MacOS 10.15 (not Beta).