# iOS Simulator is not installing the app at this time

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

When I run the newly created iOS app in iPhone 11 simulator(iOS 13) I'm getting the following error.

> This app could not be installed at this time.

[image]

**Error Log:**

> com.apple.dt.Xcode[32819] : installApplication:withOptions:error:: Error Domain=IXUserPresentableErrorDomain Code=1 "This app could not be installed at this time." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fc48881db10 {Error Domain=LSApplicationWorkspaceErrorDomain Code=-102 "(null)" UserInfo={Error=RegistrationFailed, _LSLine=627, _LSFunction=-[_LSInstaller _doinstallApplication:atURL:withOptions:installType:notificationJournaller:reply:], CFBundleIdentifier=com.boopathy.TestingApp}}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Could not install at this time., NSLocalizedDescription=This app could not be installed at this time.}

**Configuration Details:**

- macOS - Catalina 10.15 Beta(19A487m)
- Xcode - 11.3(11C29)
- Simulator - 11.3 (SimulatorApp-912.5 SimulatorKit-570.3
  CoreSimulator-681.17)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47760643/xcode-this-app-could-not-be-installed-at-this-time

Comment: Can you file a radar (feedback assistant report) at http://bugreport.apple.com with the full error message and a tarball generated by `xcrun simctl diagnose` just after the error is thrown.  Xcode 11 should be presenting you with a detailed error dialog with the full error chain here, but it looks like the underlying error is completely unhelpful (-102 "(null)").

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia I've already filed it in the feedback assistant.

Comment: What is the FB number?

Comment: FB7528106 - JeremyHuddlestonSequoia